# Can't find native method using JNI when extending Android component

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I got a class to extend `NumberPicker` component to introduce min & max value:

```
public class ExtendedNumberPicker extends NumberPicker {
    public ExtendedNumberPicker(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExtendedNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        processAttributeSet(attrs);
    }

    public ExtendedNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        processAttributeSet(attrs);
    }
    private void processAttributeSet(AttributeSet attrs) {
        //This method reads the parameters given in the xml file and sets the properties according to it
        this.setMinValue(attrs.getAttributeIntValue(null, "min", 0));
        this.setMaxValue(attrs.getAttributeIntValue(null, "max", 0));
    }
}
```

I put it into layout:

```
<com.example.myapp.component.ExtendedNumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/pick_hh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        min="140"
        max="200" />
```

In LogCat, it shows:

```
Tag                    Text
---------------------------
PropertyValuesHolder   Can't find native method using JNI, use reflectionjava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='setSelectorPaintAlpha' signature='(I)V' in class Lcom/example/myapp/component/ExtendedNumberPicker;
PropertyValuesHolder   Couldn't find setter/getter for property selectorPaintAlpha with value type int
```

I know JNI is Java Native Interface, but I never use/see the property `selectorPaintAlpha`. What is it? How to resolve the issue?

Comment: are you solve this problem ?

Comment: No, I didn't. I avoid this issue by changing to another component, but I still want to solve this problem.